# Angular Navbar Menu - Aligning the menu item with the submenu

Tags: html, css, angular, navbar

I am trying to align the menu item with the submenu. For example **D Title** has 2 subtitles as **D Subtitle 1** and **D Subtitle 2** and both of them has inner titles. But when I hover **D Subtitle 2**, the inner menu is not aligning with it. I have tried `relative` and `absolute` for `innermenu` class but it didn't work. How can I achieve it?

Source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tzksqa

[image]

navbar.component.html

```
<div class="header" *ngFor='let menu of navigationService.navMenu'>
    <div class="header-title" (mouseover)="navigationService.openMenu(menu)">
        <p>{{menu.title}}</p>
    </div>

    <div [hidden]="!menu.isOpen">
        <div class="submenu" *ngIf="menu.menu">
            <span *ngFor="let submenu of menu.menu">
                <div class="submenu-item" (mouseover)="navigationService.openSubMenu(submenu)">
                    <p>{{submenu.title}}</p>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="menu.menu">
        <span *ngFor="let submenu of menu.menu">
            <div [hidden]="!submenu.isOpen">
                <div class="innermenu" *ngIf="submenu.innerMenu">
                    <span *ngFor="let innerMenuItem of submenu.innerMenu">
                        <div class="innermenu-item">
                            <p *ngIf="innerMenuItem.title">{{innerMenuItem.title}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

navbar.component.less

```
:host {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400x;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;

    .header {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        height: 40px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 0 10px;

        .header-title {
            line-height: 40px;

            & > p {
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0 4px 0 8px;
            }
        }
    }

    .submenu {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 0;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: black;
        padding: 6px 0;

        .submenu-item {
            position: relative;
            padding: 5px 8px;
            
            & > p {
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0 4px 0 8px;
            }
        }
    }

    .innermenu {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 6px 0;
        background-color: black;

        .innermenu-item {
            position: relative;
            padding: 5px 8px;

            & > p {
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0 4px 0 8px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the result you want to achieve ? I am not sure to understand well.

Comment: Want to achieve like https://bootstrap-menu.com/demos/multilevel.html @Jeiraon

Comment: @Jeiraon, have you checked the source code? You can hover D Subtitle 2, the inner menu is not aligning.

Comment: Added solution check my answer @nanokozmos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hgzrej

`absolute` will work when you child inside parent div. You loop is also duplicated. I remove that part. Achieve multilevel submenu you have keep nested tree structure maintain.

**Note** : An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

Changes :

```
 .innermenu {
  top:-2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" *ngFor='let menu of navigationService.navMenu'>
   <div class="header-title" (mouseover)="navigationService.openMenu(menu)">
      <p>{{menu.title}}</p>
   </div>
   <div [hidden]="!menu.isOpen">
      <div class="submenu" *ngIf="menu.menu">
         <span *ngFor="let submenu of menu.menu">
            <div class="submenu-item" (mouseover)="navigationService.openSubMenu(submenu)">
               <p>{{submenu.title}}</p>
               
                   
                     <div [hidden]="!submenu.isOpen">
                        <div class="innermenu" *ngIf="submenu.innerMenu">
                           <span *ngFor="let innerMenuItem of submenu.innerMenu">
                              <div class="innermenu-item">
                                 <p *ngIf="innerMenuItem.title">{{innerMenuItem.title}}</p>
                              </div>
                           </span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                   
              
            </div>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Why do we have to give ```top:-2px```? Where is this -2 coming from?

Comment: I added in component css. its based on top menu alignment,